# How to set PowerShell binary module cmdlet prefixes in code

Tags: powershell

Currently I'm defining my cmdlet like so:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "MyPrefixDatabase")]
public class TestDatabase : DatabaseCmdlet
    {
...
```

But ideally I just want to omit *MyPrefix* and have that value set globally for all cmdlets in the assembly.

I'm aware that PowerShell 4.0 supports `DefaultCommandPrefix` in module manifests, and also `Import-Module` can take a -`Prefix` parameter, but I want to do this in code.

Comment: Why bother? :S That's what manifests are for. And it's not like you replace the prefix every day (I hope). Can't you add a buildaction or something that adds it with regex if missing?